# Applet MySQL connection

Tags: java, mysql, database, applet

This is simple sign up page. user puts his username and password and its supposed to be store in the DB.

The problem is it does not store the data in database. For testing purposing, I did a main method and it worked just fine, but from the applet it did not. it does not give me any error though.

By the way, I added the MySQL Java connector.

I know it's a bad idea to directly connect applet with MySQL but I'm doing this for a school assignment. I looked for mostly ever available source online but I could not find an answer.

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class DBConnect
{
    public DBConnect(){    
}

public String getCon(String name, String password) {
     Connection con = null;
     PreparedStatement pst = null;
       String ur1 = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test";
        String user = "root";
        String pass = "";
      try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
         con = DriverManager.getConnection(ur1, user, pass);
         pst =con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO persons (name, password) VALUES (?,?)");
         pst.setString(1, name);
         pst.setString(2, password);
         pst.executeUpdate();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(DBConnect.class.getName());
            lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);

        } finally {
            try {
                if (pst != null) {
                    pst.close();
                }
                if (con != null) {
                    con.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(DBConnect.class.getName());
                lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
            }
    }
    return name;
  }
}
```

---

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.applet.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Table extends JApplet implements ActionListener
{
    TextField username, password;
     public String s1,s2,s;
      String msg ="";
      private Thread th;
      Button submit;
      Label LabelName, LabelPass;
      DBConnect connect = new DBConnect();

    public Table(){
    }

    public void init()
    {
           setLayout(null);
           username = new TextField(8);
           password = new TextField(8);
           submit = new Button ("Register");
           LabelName = new Label("User Name");
           LabelPass = new Label("Password");

           username.setBounds(100,40,80,20);
           password.setBounds(100,80,80,20);
           submit.setBounds(40,110,80,30);
           LabelName.setBounds(20,40,80,20);
           LabelPass.setBounds(20,80,80,20);

           add(LabelName);
           add(username);
           add(LabelPass);
           add(password);
           add(submit);

         submit.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
      g.drawString(s1,100,275); // just for a test purpose
      g.drawString(s2,100,300); // just for a test purpose
    }

         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
         {
              if (evt.getSource() == submit) {
         try
          {
           s1 = username.getText();
           s2 = password.getText();
           repaint();
           connect.getCon(s1, s2); // here is the problem
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "you're registered");
        }
          catch(Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Something Wrong / This user name already exists");
            }
          }
        }

        public String getS1(){
            return s1;
        }

        public String getS2(){
            return s2;
        }
}
```

Comment: Even ignoring the direct access of the DB, that applet has a lot of problems. 1) Don't mix Swing and AWT components when not needed. 2) ***Use layouts!*** 3) Don't mix custom painting and components unless you **really** know what your doing. (Hint: *you don't*). 4) Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use them consistently. E.G. `LabelName` should be `labelName` ..

Comment: *"I know it's a bad idea to directly connect applet with MySQL but I'm doing this for a school assignment."*  Inform your teacher that the only point of getting students to make applets (it is quick and easy) was never really true and has just become a lot less true given Oracle's latest take on [applets and security](http://blog.eisele.net/2013/04/java-7-update-21-security-improvements.html).  E.G. an applet will basically need to be in a Jar and digitally signed before it has a good chance of making it to screen.

Comment: Please direct your teacher to [Why should CS teachers stop teaching applets?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/196499/why-should-cs-teachers-stop-teaching-applets?noredirect=1#comment380828_196499).  It is especially relevant in that your post inspired me to write it.

Comment: if you know so mush about this. why dont you help me get my assignment done?

Comment: @user2330797: Have you tried all four of my "suggestions" below?  I'm pretty sure the answer was "Yes" for at least 1) and 2) - even before I suggested them.  Please confirm, 1) .. 4).  Thank you in advance...

Comment: *"why dont you help"*  You already have answers, and there is no evidence you are following (or following up on) the advice I offer.  Why should I bother?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the User, Password you enter belong to a database login, usually you log this data with a separated connection so it does not dependon "if the user/pass you enter can access your DB or not", you can debug to see if your code to insert data is getting executed at all, and check the result of [`pst.executeUpdate();`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate%28%29) to see if any updates to the database was done.

*PS. Having a method called `getConnection(name, password)` one would expect it to return a `Connection` or any default value on failure not a `String`.*

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's a real bad idea to connect directly from an applet to MySQL.  In the real world, you shouldn't do it.

Suggestions:

1. Write a standalone app to verify connectivity (it sounds like you've already done this)
2. Verify there's no firewall preventing MySQL connections (it sounds like you've done this, too)
3. Verify your logger actually writes from the applet (you'd hate to lose a meaningful error message)
4. Consider signing your applet:

   - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/rsa_signing.html
   - http://sickpea.com/2009/7/how-to-self-sign-a-java-applet
   - http://www.brendonwilson.com/projects/signed-java/

Comment: *"SUGGESTIONS"*  Ughh. 1) Don't shout. 2) Use bullet notation for bullet points. 3) Don't post naked links. At least include the page title. -- 1st 2 fixed, 3rd left as an exercise for you.

Comment: Hi paulsm4, thanks for your response I've check all of them but nothing seemed to help much. I found out where the problem exactly, but yet i dont know how to fix it. everything in the Applet class is fine, but when it tries to connect, it gives my an exception error.

Comment: though i tried to make simple Main static void.... method and it worked just fine
thank you anyways